# Abstract classes and metaclasses with dataclasses in python

Tags: python, java, mongodb

I'm trying to isolate a field and a method from classes to work with mongodb.

Example of the working class:

```
@dataclass
class Article(Mongodata):
    name: str
    quantity: int
    description: str

    _id: Optional[int] = None

    def __getdict__(self):
        result = asdict(self)
        result.pop("_id")
        return result
```

How can I isolate _id and **getdict** into an abstract class so that everything works.

```
@dataclass
class Article(Mongodata):
    name: str
    quantity: int
    description: str

@dataclass
class Mongodata(ABCMeta):
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def _id(self) -> Optional[int]:
        return None

    def __getdict__(self):
        result = asdict(self)
        result.pop("_id")
        return result
```

Can you explain how abstract and metaclasses differ, and I came from java, and after reading about it I didn't understand anything?

Comment: Abstract classes are basically what interfaces are in Python. They are like interfaces in Java, except you can also define concrete variables and methods, if so desired.

Comment: On the other hand, metaclasses perform a different functionality altogether. A use case for them is generating some dunder methods like `__or__` and adding them to a class before creating it, or modifying some existing methods and variables before the class definition is finalized. They are mainly useful to perform additional setup before creating a class.

Comment: So just to clarify, you want `_id` to be a dataclass field? That is, you want to be able to pass in a value for `_id` into the __init__() constructor when creating a new class object?

Comment: Not quite. I want it to automatically assign the value None.

Comment: Hmm, think I understand, so `_id` should be an optional field that defaults to None if not passed in. Just curious, are you using Python 3.10? because in 3.10 there is a new param `kw_only` added to the dataclass decorator, which allows you to resolve the issue that might arise here, where you have a field with a default value in the superclass. That will of course only allow keyword arguments to passed in to the constructor in that case, and disallow any positional arguments.

Comment: at the moment 3.9.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you mentioned you're on Python 3.9, you can set it up the same way you had it above, however if you declare the fields in `Article` as above and add a field definition in the superclass like below:

```py
@dataclass
class Mongodata(ABC):
    _id: Optional[int] = None
```

Then if you actually try to run the code, you would run into a `TypeError` as below:

```
TypeError: non-default argument 'name' follows default argument
```

The reason for this is the order in which `dataclasses` resolves the fields for a dataclass when inheritance is involved. In this case, it adds the `_id` field from the superclass first, and then all the fields in the `Article` dataclass next. Since the first param that it adds has a default value, but the params that follow it *don't* have a default value, it'll raise a `TypeError` as you might expect.

Note that you'd actually run into the same behavior if you had decided to manually generate an `__init__` method for the Article class in the same way:

```
    def __init__(self, _id: Optional[int] = None, name: str, quantity: int, description: str):
                                                             ^
SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument
```

The best approach in Python 3.9, seems to be declare the dataclasses this way, so that all fields in the subclass have default values:

```py
from abc import ABC
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict
from typing import Optional


@dataclass
class Mongodata(ABC):
    _id: Optional[int] = None

    def __getdict__(self):
        result = asdict(self)
        result.pop("_id")
        return result


@dataclass
class Article(Mongodata):

    name: str = None
    quantity: int = None
    description: str = None
```

But then positional arguments from creating an `Article` object will be a problem, because it'll assign the first argument passed in to the constructor to `_id`:

```
a = Article('123', 321, 'desc')
```

So you could instead pass `None` as the first positional argument, and that'll get assigned to `_id`. Another approach that works, is to then pass keyword arguments into the constructor instead:

```
a = Article(name='123', quantity=321, description='desc')
```

This actually feels more natural with the [`kw_only`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.KW_ONLY) param that was introduced to dataclasses in Python 3.10 as a means to resolve this same issue, but more on that below.

##### A Metaclass Approach

Another option is to declare a function which can be used as a metaclass, as below:

```py
from dataclasses import asdict
from typing import Optional


def add_id_and_get_dict(name: str, bases: tuple[type, ...], cls_dict: dict):
    """Metaclass to add an `_id` field and a `get_dict` method."""

    # Get class annotations
    cls_annotations = cls_dict['__annotations__']
    # This assigns the `_id: Optional[int]` annotation
    cls_annotations['_id'] = Optional[int]
    # This assigns the `_id = None` assignment
    cls_dict['_id'] = None

    def get_dict(self):
        result = asdict(self)
        result.pop('_id')
        return result

    # add get_dict() method to the class
    cls_dict['get_dict'] = get_dict

    # create and return a new class
    cls = type(name, bases, cls_dict)
    return cls
```

Then you can simplify your dataclass definition a little. Also you technically don't need to define a `get_dict` method here, but it's useful so that an IDE knows that such a method exists on the class.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Any


@dataclass
class Article(metaclass=add_id_and_get_dict):

    name: str
    quantity: int
    description: str

    # Add for type hinting, so the IDE knows such a method exists.
    def get_dict(self) -> dict[str, Any]:
        ...
```

And now it's a bit more intuitive when you want to create new `Article` objects:

```py
a = Article('abc', 123, 'desc')
print(a)             # Article(name='abc', quantity=123, description='desc', _id=None)
print(a._id)         # None
print(a.get_dict())  # {'name': 'abc', 'quantity': 123, 'description': 'desc'}

a2 = Article('abc', 321, 'desc', _id=12345)
print(a2)               # Article(name='abc', quantity=321, description='desc', _id=12345)
print(a2._id)           # 12345
print(a2.get_dict())    # {'name': 'abc', 'quantity': 321, 'description': 'desc'}
```

##### *Keyword-only* Arguments

In Python 3.10, if you don't want to assign default values to all the fields in a subclass, another option is to decorate the superclass with `@dataclass(kw_only=True)`, so that fields defined in that class are then required to be *keyword-only* arguments by default.

You can also use the `KW_ONLY` sentinel value as a type annotation which is provided in dataclasses in Python 3.10 as shown below, which should also make things much simpler and more intuitive to work with.

```py
from abc import ABC
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict, KW_ONLY
from typing import Optional


@dataclass
class Mongodata(ABC):
    _: KW_ONLY
    _id: Optional[int] = None

    @property
    def dict(self):
        result = asdict(self)
        result.pop("_id")
        return result


# noinspection PyDataclass
@dataclass
class Article(Mongodata):

    name: str
    quantity: int
    description: str
```

Essentially, any fields defined after the `_: KW_ONLY` then become keyword-only arguments to the constructor.

Now the usage should be exactly as desired. You can pass both keyword and positional arguments to the constructor, and it appears to work as intended:

```py
a = Article(name='123', quantity=123, description='desc')
print(a)        # Article(_id=None, name='123', quantity=123, description='desc')
print(a._id)    # None
print(a.dict)   # {'name': '123', 'quantity': 123, 'description': 'desc'}

a2 = Article('123', 321, 'desc', _id=112233)
print(a2)        # Article(_id=112233, name='123', quantity=321, description='desc')
print(a2._id)    # 112233
print(a2.dict)   # {'name': '123', 'quantity': 321, 'description': 'desc'}
```

---

Also, just a quick explanation that I've been able to come up with, on why this appears to work as it does. Since you've only decorated the superclass as `kw_only=True`, all this accomplishes is in making `_id` as a keyword-only argument to the constructor. The fields in the subclass are allowed as either keyword or positional arguments, since we didn't specify `kw_only` for them.

An easier way to think about this, is to imagine that the signature of the `__init__()` method that `dataclasses` generates, actually looks like this:

```
def __init__(self, name: str, quantity: int, description: str, *, _id: Optional[int] = None):
```

In Python (not necessarily in 3.10 alone), the appearance of `*` in a function signifies that all the parameters that follow it are then declared as keyword-only arguments. Note that the `_id` argument, in this case is added as a keyword-argument *after* all the positional arguments from the subclass. This means that the method signature is valid, since it's certainly possible for keyword-only arguments to a method to have default values as we do here.